# convert categorial variables into integers using pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to convert categorical variables into integers. However, I want them to use the same key (A gets converted to 1 across all fields. My below code does not use the same keys.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['A', 'A', 'C', 'D','B']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['D', 'D', 'B', 'A','A']})

df1_int = pd.factorize(df1['A'])[0]
print df1_int

df2_int = pd.factorize(df2['A'])[0]
print df2_int
```

This is the output I get:

```
    [0 0 1 2 3]
    [0 0 1 2 2]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're trying to learn categories from one DataFrame to apply to a different DataFrame, using scikit-learn might provide a more elegant solution:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['A', 'A', 'C', 'D','B'],
                    'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three','four']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['D', 'D', 'B', 'A','A'],
                    'B' : ['one', 'five', 'two', 'three','four']})

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
df1_int = le.fit_transform(df1['A'])
print df1_int

df2_int = le.transform(df2['A'])
print df2_int
```

Results in:

```
[0 0 2 3 1]
[3 3 1 0 0]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can convert the existing columns to a categorical dtype, and when you use the same categories for both, the underlying integer values (which you can access as the `codes` through `Series.cat.codes`) will be consistent between both dataframes:

```
In [5]: df1['A'].astype('category', categories=list('ABCD')).cat.codes
Out[5]:
0    0
1    0
2    2
3    3
4    1
dtype: int8

In [6]: df2['A'].astype('category', categories=list('ABCD')).cat.codes
Out[6]:
0    3
1    3
2    1
3    0
4    0
dtype: int8
```

If you don't want to specify the categories manually, you can also reuse the categories of the first dataframe for the second to ensure they are the same:

```
df1['A'] = df1['A'].astype('category')
df2['A'] = df2['A'].astype('category', categories=df1['A'].cat.categories)
```

Note: the `astype('category', categories=...)` only works for pandas >= 0.16, with pandas 0.15 you can first convert it to a category dtype and afterwards set the categories with `set_categories` (see [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#setting-categories)).

Comment: For people from the future like me, `categories=` is no longer an `astype` kwarg and `.astype('categories')` will infer the categories.